# How to Delete DataRow from DataTable quickly

Tags: c#, datarow

I input data in DataTable in column direction.

```
for(int i=0 ; i<mTable.Count ; i++){
  Table.Columns.Add(i);
  foreach(DataRow row in Table.Rows){
    if(result == 1)
      row[i] = result;
    else
      row[i] = null;
  }
}
```

From here, If All data of column is null, I want to delete row.

For example,

> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 6 7 8 9 10
>
> 11 12 13 14 15
>
> 16 17 18 19 20

11, 12, 13, 14, 15 are null, I want to delete Table.Rows[2].

So, I use next way.

```
for(int i = Table.Rows.Count-1;i >= 0;i--)
{
                for (int j = 0; j < mTable.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (Table.Rows[i][j] != null)
                        break;
                    if(j == mTable.Count-1)
                        Table.Rows.Remove(Table.Rows[i]);
                }
}
```

But, If There's a lot of data, It will slow down considerably.

Is there another fast way?

Comment: Your first code snippet looks incomplete. Can you please post all the variable declaration also along with the for loop in your first code snippet? We have no clue about `Table` and `result` variables being used there.

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is bad so in the end it is not clear what you want to achieve. What if 11, 12 ,13, 20 and 1 are null, are we going to remove row 1,3,4 ?

Comment: Table is DataTable. and mTable is just List.(so, I declared lke List<int> mTable ~~). and result is data of mTable.

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 means cell of dataTable(Table). so Table.Rows[0][0] = 1, Table.Rows[1][1] = 7.

Comment: @SuYeonChoi It is always better to add code related information in the post itself so that reader doesn't have to go through comments just to understand your code snippet. So, I would suggest that you add this information in the post itself. Btw, `mTable` is a horrible name for a list variable. Please consider naming it anything but `mTable`.

Comment: Your code gives compilation error - `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Data.DataColumn'`. You can't add integers to `Columns` collection of a `DataTable`. Please learn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to write minimal, complete, and verifiable code in an SO post.

Answer (score 0):

You algorithm is probably the quickest method.  But you can can a little bit better performance with a few improvements

```
            int numberOfCols = Table.Columns.Count;
            for (int i = Table.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Boolean delete = true;
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfCols; j++)
                {
                    if (Table.Rows[i][j] != null)
                    {
                        delete = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (delete)
                {
                    Table.Rows.Remove(Table.Rows[i]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure you can modify the collection will enumerating it?

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins he is *not* using `foreach` construct which constrains you against modifying the collection while enumerating it. He is using a reverse countdown `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the rows, you can select the non null rows from your table.

```
public void DtSelect()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        var columns = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => "Col" + x).ToList();
        columns.ForEach(x => dt.Columns.Add(x));
        Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToList().ForEach(x =>
         {
             var row = dt.NewRow();
             if (x % 15 == 0) columns.ForEach(z => row[z] = x);
             dt.Rows.Add(row);
         });
         var query =  "(" + string.Join(" is not null) or (", columns) + " is not null)";

        var nonEmpty = dt.Select(query).CopyToDataTable();


    }
```

`nonEmpty` will not be a datatable with all rows that are non empty;

Comment: Was typing up an example.